# Summary by next row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below source table Sales

```
Billnumber   Item          Amount        Total
1            Item1                        100
1            Disc A           10
1            Item2                        200
1            Item3                        200
1            Disc B           15
```

And I want to select and sum all item minus discount in each item. The desired result is below:

```
Billnumber    item         Total
1             Item1          90
1             Item2         200
1             Item3         185
```

Is it possible to sum the disc without parent information on disc item?

Comment: How on earth do you know which `item` a `disc` refers to?

Comment: No, this isn't possible without another column which provides the ordering of the transactions.

Comment: @andereana your question seem not right because u want grouping item in output expecting but data insert it table incorrect way please make that like if u want discount in appropiriate item make item description same so when grouping getting output in as u expected...
change item decription 
here m explaing for that thing
insert into bill(billnumber,item,amount,total)
select 1,'item1',0,100
union
select 1,'item1',10,0
union
select 1,'item2',0,200
union
select 1,'item3',0,200
union
select 1,'item3',15,0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
create table bill(billnumber int,item nvarchar(1000),amount int,total int)
   
insert into bill(billnumber,item,amount,total)
    select 1,'item1',0,100
    union
    select 1,'item1',10,0
    union
    select 1,'item2',0,200
    union
    select 1,'item3',0,200
    union
    select 1,'item3',15,0
    
select billnumber, item, sum(total)
from (
    select billnumber, item, sum(total) total from bill where total > 0
    group by billnumber, item
    union all
    select billnumber, item, sum(-amount) from bill where amount > 0
    group by billnumber, item
) as a
group by billnumber, item
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation as well as working code.

Comment: But you did not use OP's data - you changed it.